# Sorting array of Dictionary by weekday name swift3

Tags: ios, sorting, swift3

I want to sort the root array by weekday name. Like on first index of the root array there should be Sunday, Monday,Tuesday and so on.

```
[{

    day = Monday;
    timingValues =     (
                {
            closeHour = 23;
            closeMin = 55;
            day = Monday;
            id = 2;
            openHour = 00;
            openMin = 00;
        }
    );
}, 

{

 day = Tuesday;

    timingValues =     (

                {
            closeHour = 00;
            closeMin = 11;
            day = Tuesday;
            id = 4;
            openHour = 12;
            openMin = 10;
        }
    );
}, {

    day = Sunday;
    timingValues =   (
                {
            closeHour = 23;
            closeMin = 07;
            day = Sunday;
            id = 5;
            openHour = 11;
            openMin = 07;
        }

);

}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of force unwrap, but you can get the idea of comparing, also need to make sure the string is correct, I'm just doing 1 line here as reference, it's not safe, in real code should do optional check.

```
let dictArray = [["day": "Monday", "timingValues" : 1],
                     ["day" : "Tuesday", "timingValues" : 2],
                     ["day" : "Saturday", "timingValues" : 3],
                     ["day" : "Sunday", "timingValues" : 4]]
let b = dictArray.sorted(by: { DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols.index(of: ($0["day"]! as! String))! < DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols.index(of: ($1["day"]! as! String))! })
```

Result:

```
[["day": "Sunday", "timingValues": 4], ["day": "Monday", "timingValues": 1], ["day": "Tuesday", "timingValues": 2], ["day": "Saturday", "timingValues": 3]]
```

Comment: Great! It's working. you have saved my time. Thank you.

Comment: @ShashiDev Not forcing you to prefer any answer over another, but consider using the idea of `Weekday` type combined with optional cast (using `?` and not `!`) from my answer. It is MUCH safer and you will have less problems supporting it in future.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the format of Dictionary in your question doesn't match Swift's syntax for that. I presume you know it, and you have a proper Swift dictionary with this structure. See [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113).

Next, you should define your custom type for weekday like this (note that week starts with Sunday here):

```
enum Weekday: Int {
    case sunday = 0, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday
}
```

Make sure you create dictionary using this type as a key for day value.

Given that you have everything set up properly, you should be able to get sorted array like this:

```
let sortedArray = initialArray.sorted { (element0, element1) -> Bool in
    guard let day0 = element0["day"] as? Weekday, let day1 = element1["day"] as? Weekday else {
        // Default behaviour in case you used wrong Weekday type or didn't set it at all 
        return false
    }

    return day0 < day1
}
```

Comment: Sure.! Thanks for replying.